# how to call a method in an object following the factory pattern

Tags: javascript

I would like to display name, age, job in an alert message box, how do I do that?

```
function createPerson(name, age, job) {
    var o = new Object();
    o.name = name;
    o.age = age;
    o.job = job;
    o.sayName = function () {
        alert(this.name);
    };
    return o;
}
var person1 = createPerson('Nicholas', 29, 'Software Engineer');
var person2 = createPerson('Greg', 27, 'Doctor');
```

Comment: You need to call the `sayName` method. Use `person1.sayName();`

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/apVJT/1)***

"I would like to display name, age, job in an alert message box, how do I do that?"

Access the properties on the object using `.name`, `.age`, and `.job` like this:
 `alert(person1.name+" "+person1.age+" "+person1.job);` from the outside. If you would like to have the object be able to use this alert then you can attach it like this:

`o.alertInformation = function(){ alert(this.name+" "+this.age+" "+this.job); };`

```
function createPerson(name, age, job){
 var o = new Object();
 o.name = name;
 o.age = age;
 o.job = job;
 o.sayName = function(){
  alert(this.name);
 };
 o.alertInformation = function(){ alert(this.name+" "+this.age+" "+this.job); };
 return o;
}

var person1 = createPerson('Nicholas', 29, 'Software Engineer');
var person2 = createPerson('Greg', 27, 'Doctor');

//example of accessing the object properties with dot notation
//alternatively, you could use person1["name"] to access them
alert(person1.name+" "+person1.age+" "+person1.job);

//or if you want to use an internal method on person
person1.alertInformation();
```

---

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/xMnSV/)***

Blurb on "factory" pattern:

Usually an approach is used where the `new` keyword is called on a function. When `new` is used on a function, it creates a scope in the function where `this` refers to the function object. Using `this.name` inside of a function called with `new` will attach `name` to the object. When you use `new`, it implicitly assigns the function object to the variable, in the below example, `p` is used.

```
function Person(name, age, job){
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.job = job;
}

Person.prototype.sayName = function(){
 alert(this.name);
};

Person.prototype.alertInformation = function(){   
 alert(this.name+" "+this.age+" "+this.job);
};

var p = new Person('Nicholas', 29, 'Software Engineer');
p.sayName();
p.alertInformation();
```

---

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/yR6Nh/)***

For this to be an actual factory, remember that it has to be involved with the actual *creation* of the objects, not just implicitly returning them. To do this, we would need a PersonFactory (sounds strange :P).

```
function personFactory(){
 var People = [];
 var autoIncId = 0;
 return {
  Create: function(name,age,job){
   var p = new Person(autoIncId++,name,age,job);
   People.push(p);
   return p;      
  },
  GetPersonById: function(id){
   return People[id];       
  }
 };
}
```

which would then be used:

```
var pf = personFactory();

var p = pf.Create('Nicholas', 29, 'Software Engineer');
p.sayName();
p.alertInformation();
```

Comment: this is known as the factory method, does anyone use this kind of pattern  anymore ?

Comment: @CartrightMellisa - Yes, this pattern is still widely used. Although the implementation may vary slightly. In javascript this pattern is also known as the module pattern although it usually includes using the `new` keyword on a function rather than actually creating an object in the fashion you have shown.

Comment: @CartrightMellisa - Please see edit for some details on the more common implementation of creating these objects.

Answer (score -1):

```
function createPerson(name, age, job){
this.name=name;
this.age=age;
this.job=job;
if(createPerson._intialized=="undefined"){
    createPerson.prototype.sayPersonInfo=function(){
          alert('i am '+this.name+' , '+this.age+'years old and my job is '+this.job);
}
createPerson._initialized=true;
}
var person1 = createPerson('Nicholas', 29, 'Software Engineer');
var person2 = createPerson('Greg', 27, 'Doctor');
person1.sayPersonInfo();
```

this method is called ' dynamic prototype ' and is the best way in know .
i hope this can help ...